# RegEx to support letters only, in two groups separated by a period, with a restriction on the second group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a url rewrite regex expression. So if the url is bob.smith then good, if it's home.aspx, then not.

I have this so far:

```html
^[a-zA-Z\-]+[.](?!aspx$|js$|css$|html$|htm$)[a-zA-Z\-]+$
```

So, first group, upper or lower case letters, the period, then the second group, upper or lower case letters, but not aspx, js, cs, html, htm.

Am i on the right track here?

Comment: You just missed a `+` to say the `[a-zA-Z]` can match more than one character: `^[a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+(?!aspx|js|css|html|htm)$`

Comment: The lookahead has to be placed directly after the dot. You might want to include an end of string anchor and use a case insensitivity modifier.

Comment: As side note, you can short `html|htm` to just `html?`

Comment: I've updated the regex. I'm testing in http://regexr.com/

Comment: Are you sure you want to forbid the use of dashes, underscores, digits and such? That looks over-restrictive if the goal only is to forbid some file extensions

Comment: Good point. Maybe it's a two step. If the URL matches a file extenstion, fail, else continue. I'm trying to match a firstname.lastname, so hyphens are a possible too.

Comment: What language/tool?

Comment: You regex, which seems OK, can be shortened to `^[a-zA-Z-]+\.(?!(aspx|js|css|html?)$)[a-zA-Z-]+$`

Comment: We're implimenting this is the IIS URLmodule. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z-]+\.(?!(?:aspx|js|css|html?)$)[a-zA-Z-]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SHSdca/1/) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z-%5D%2B%5C.(%3F!(%3F%3Aaspx%7Cjs%7Ccss%7Chtml%3F)%24)%5Ba-zA-Z-%5D%2B%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z-]+` - 1 or more letters or hyphens
- `\.` - a dot
  -`(?!(?:aspx|js|css|html?)$)` - after the dot, there should not be `aspx`, `js`, `css`, `htm` or `html` at the end of the string
- `[a-zA-Z-]+` - 1+ letters or hyphens
- `$` - end of string.